# PGError: Error: column of relation does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, migration

I'm trying to change the value of a column "isGroup" to the value "public".

I created a migration:

```
Post.connection.execute("update Posts set isgroup='public'")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  column "isgroup" of relation "posts" does not exist
```

I had unfortunately ran the column creating migration at the same time as the connection.execute migration.   However, the "isGroup" column does exist on Heroku, so it is weird that the column is not showing as appearing.

Any advice?

Comment: did you do `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: yes, the error is what i get when running that command...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you are sure that column `isGroup` exists, then you should quote it like:

```
UPDATE posts SET "isGroup" = 'public'
```

Note that PostgreSQL by default folds all unquoted named to lowercase.

To avoid this confusion and necessity to quote, you might want to rename `isGroup` to `isgroup` using `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME COLUMN ...`.

Comment: not sure I understand... so the command looks like this?  Post.connection.execute("UPDATE posts SET "isGroup" = 'public'") the quotes causes a syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'

Comment: Also, the column definitely exists, as I can change individual values in rails_admin...also, I can run other column changes...ugh

Comment: if `SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1` shows `isGroup` column, then it certainly does exist. in that case, you must either use quoting like `...execute("UPDATE posts SET \"isGroup\" = 'public'")`, or rename column to `isgroup`

Comment: Glad it helped you. It just goes to show that under Postgres you should always use lowercase names for tables and columns - or you can get nasty surprises like this one

Comment: Thanks! solved by making all columns as **lowercase**