# How do sub-queries contained within queries work in pg-promise when using transactions?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I am using `pg-promise` for node.js, and I wanted to make sure I am understanding the documentation about transactions correctly.

Say I executed the following transaction:

```
db.tx(function(t) {
  t.any('SELECT * FROM users')
  .then(function(users) {
    var queries = [];
    for (var i =0; i < users.length; i++) {
      queries.push(t.any("INSERT INTO stocks_owned (ticker, shares, user_id) VALUES ('GOOG', 10, $1)", users[i].user_id));
    }
    return t.batch(queries);
  })
})
```

What postgres queries will this end up performing?

Will the postgres transaction be:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM users;
SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
INSERT INTO stocks_owned (ticker, shares, user_id) VALUES ('GOOG', 10, 1);
INSERT INTO stocks_owned (ticker, shares, user_id) VALUES ('GOOG', 10, 2);
...
INSERT INTO stocks_owned (ticker, shares, user_id) VALUES ('GOOG', 10, 999);
COMMIT;
```

In other words, do sub-queries contained within other queries get included in the same `BEGIN/COMMIT` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What postgres queries will this end up performing?

The ones you listed, except there won't be any `SAVEPOINT`, because savepoints are used in place of nested transactions only.

> do sub-queries contained within other queries get included in the same BEGIN/COMMIT block?

There is no such thing as sub-queries, from the driver point of view, there are just queries, and all those executed inside a transaction will be inside `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` block.

---

To see what is being executed by `pg-promise` exactly, you should use [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), or at the very least - handle [event query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query):

```
var pgOptions = {
    query: function (e) {
        console.log(e.query); // log the query being executed
    }
};

var pgp = require('pg-promise')(pgOptions);
```

---

The following is a mistake in your code:

```
t.any('SELECT * FROM users')
```

which is supposed to be:

```
return t.any('SELECT * FROM users')
```

or else there is no transaction logic there, since you are not returning anything from the callback.

The shortest and most efficient way to do what you were trying there:

```
db.tx(t => {
    return t.map('SELECT * FROM users', [], user => {
        return t.none("INSERT INTO stocks_owned(ticker, shares, user_id) VALUES('GOOG', 10, ${user_id})", user);
    }).then(t.batch);
})
    .then(data => {
        // success, data = [null, null, ...]
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error
    });
```

**UPDATE**

The above example is no longer the most efficient way to do it. The most efficient approach would be to execute one select, and then a single multi-row insert. See [Multi-Row Inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).

Comment: Thank you! Your package is great btw (no raunchy pun intended). Cheers.

Comment: "There is no such thing as sub-queries". Well, there is such a thing as subqueries, but not apparently at the node-pg level. A subquery is a construct in SQL where one query contains another, e.g. `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE x = (SELECT ...)` or `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ..)`

Comment: @CraigRinger I have corrected it to explicitly say `from the driver point of view`, as this is what we were discussing, i.e. for the driver it is always just a query, irrelevant of its level.

Comment: @CraigRinger added explanation of a mistake in your code ;) Also see [Chaining Queries](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/chaining-queries).