# How to improve PostgreSQL performance on INSERT?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, postgresql, sql-insert

I have written a Node.js application that writes lots of records to a PostgreSQL 9.6 database. Unfortunately, it feels quite slow. To be able to test things I have created a [short but complete](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html) program that reproduces the scenario:

```
'use strict';

const async = require('async'),
      pg = require('pg'),
      uuid = require('uuidv4');

const pool = new pg.Pool({
  protocol: 'pg',
  user: 'golo',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'golo'
});

const records = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  records.push({ id: uuid(), revision: i, data: { foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz' }, flag: true });
}

pool.connect((err, database, close) => {
  if (err) {
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    return console.log(err);
    /* eslint-enable no-console */
  }

  database.query(`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "foo" (
      "position" bigserial NOT NULL,
      "id" uuid NOT NULL,
      "revision" integer NOT NULL,
      "data" jsonb NOT NULL,
      "flag" boolean NOT NULL,

      CONSTRAINT "foo_pk" PRIMARY KEY("position"),
      CONSTRAINT "foo_index_id_revision" UNIQUE ("id", "revision")
    );
  `, errQuery => {
    if (errQuery) {
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      return console.log(errQuery);
      /* eslint-enable no-console */
    }

    async.series({
      beginTransaction (done) {
        /* eslint-disable no-console */
        console.time('foo');
        /* eslint-enable no-console */
        database.query('BEGIN', done);
      },
      saveRecords (done) {
        async.eachSeries(records, (record, doneEach) => {
          database.query({
            name: 'save',
            text: `
              INSERT INTO "foo"
                ("id", "revision", "data", "flag")
              VALUES
                ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING position;
            `,
            values: [ record.id, record.revision, record.data, record.flag ]
          }, (errQuery2, result) => {
            if (errQuery2) {
              return doneEach(errQuery2);
            }

            record.position = Number(result.rows[0].position);
            doneEach(null);
          });
        }, done);
      },
      commitTransaction (done) {
        database.query('COMMIT', done);
      }
    }, errSeries => {
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      console.timeEnd('foo');
      /* eslint-enable no-console */
      if (errSeries) {
        return database.query('ROLLBACK', errRollback => {
          close();

          if (errRollback) {
            /* eslint-disable no-console */
            return console.log(errRollback);
            /* eslint-enable no-console */
          }
          /* eslint-disable no-console */
          console.log(errSeries);
          /* eslint-enable no-console */
        });
      }

      close();
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      console.log('Done!');
      /* eslint-enable no-console */
    });
  });
});
```

The performance I get for inserting 10.000 rows is 2.5 seconds. This is not bad, but also not great. What can I do to improve speed?

Some thoughts that I had so far:

- Use prepared statements. As you can see I have done this, this speeded up things by ~30 %.
- Insert multiple rows at once using a single `INSERT` command. Unfortunately, this is not possible, as in reality, the number of records that need to be written varies from call to call and a varying number of arguments makes it impossible to use prepared statements.
- Use `COPY` instead of `INSERT`: I can't use this, since this happens at runtime, not at initialization time.
- Use `text` instead of `jsonb`: Didn't change a thing.
- Use `json` instead of `jsonb`: Didn't change a thing either.

A few more notes on the data that happens in reality:

- The `revision` is not necessarily increasing. This is just a number.
- The `flag` is not always `true`, it can be `true` and `false` as well.
- Of course the `data` field contains different data, too.

So in the end it comes down to:

- What possibilities are there to significantly speed up multiple single calls to `INSERT`?

Comment: Are you certain that the bottleneck isn't the communication time between Node and Postgres?  Have you benchmarked those 10 inserts running directly on Postgres?

Comment: No, I am not. Please note that it's 10k inserts, not 10, so how could I do this in PostgreSQL directly? (And even if, the question then is, how to reduce the communication time between those two ;-))

Comment: 10K inserts in 2 seconds doesn't strike me as too bad.

Comment: Anyway, it's not good enough ;-)

Comment: If I put the SQL to a script file and run this from PGAdmin 4, it tells me that the query returned successfully in 1 second.

Comment: Then use this as a benchmark of sorts.  I don't know enough about Postgres to help you tune it to get under a second.

Comment: If you insert some of the 10k records in same table you can use `INSERT INTO yourTable (position, id, ...) VALUES (1, 435, ...), (2, 23, ...), (3, 546, ...)....`

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong, and you are suggesting something different, but this is what I meant by:

"Insert multiple rows at once using a single INSERT command. Unfortunately, this is not possible, as in reality, the number of records that need to be written varies from call to call and a varying number of arguments makes it impossible to use prepared statements." Am I missing something here?

Comment: Then try: Write 10k records in a file down, put it in pgadmin and wirte in front `DISTINCT ANALYZE` then you can analyze what take the most time

Comment: We also import data into pg using node.js in similar way and speed is similar. So unless you have some very strong need to speed it up I would say you solution is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Insert multiple rows at once using a single INSERT command. Unfortunately, this is not possible, as in reality, the number of records that need to be written varies from call to call and a varying number of arguments makes it impossible to use prepared statements.

This is the right answer, followed by an invalid counter-argument.

You can generate your multi-row inserts in a loop, with some 1000 - 10,000 records per query, depending on the size of the records.

And you do not need prepared statements for this at all.

See this article I wrote about the same issues: [Performance Boost](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Performance-Boost).

Following the article, my code was able to insert 10,000 records in **under 50ms**.

A related question: [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).

Comment: You're right, thanks :-). One thing to notice is that you can still combine this with (dynamically created) prepared statements, which pushes performance even more.

Comment: @GoloRoden there is a limit of some 8K parameters that can be passed in a prepared statement at once, which limits its usability for such cases.

Comment: Does this only affect prepared statements?

Comment: @GoloRoden Yes.