# NodeJS and pg-promise, insert dynamically from JSON-object

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I'm running NodeJS and pg-promise, and are trying to accomplish somethings like:

```
db.none('INSERT INTO my-table (JSON-object-keys) VALUES ($1)', [JSON-object-values])
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error on insert into my-table: ' + err);
    });
```

I have JSON-objects which can look like:

```
{"column1":"value1", "column2":"value2", "column3":"value3"}
{"column2":"value2", "column3":"value3"}
{"column1":"value1", "column3":"value3"}
```

I would like to have the INSERTS automatically generated corresponding to what the JSON-object contains.

Is that possible in an elegant way?

Explained a bit more, in the 3 examples of JSON the following should be generated:

```
db.none('INSERT INTO my-table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)', [value1, value2, value3])
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error on insert into my-table: ' + err);
    });

db.none('INSERT INTO my-table (column2, column3) VALUES ($1, $2)', [value2, value3])
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error on insert into my-table: ' + err);
    });

db.none('INSERT INTO my-table (column1, column3) VALUES ($1, $2)', [value1, value3])
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error on insert into my-table: ' + err);
    });
```

Comment: `VALUES ($1:json)`

Comment: And for the columns?

Comment: Updated with a bit more example of what I'm seeking.

Comment: The easiest way is to generate the same insert for a statically defined set of columns, and then for the columns that you do not want to insert, provide `DEFAULT` as the value. Before I can offer a usable example - what is the criteria for the columns to be skipped? - do the corresponding properties not exist or something? Also, give a complete list of columns that you have, specifying which of them can be optional.

Comment: In my testing table I have 3 columns named column1, column2 and column3. My JSON object may or may not contain all 3 columns keys - and I cannot guarantee the order in the json object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pgp` object + the input object with all the properties:

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')({
    capSQL: true // capitalize all generated SQL
});

var inputObj = {
    /* all your optional properties */
};
```

Define the [raw-text](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#raw-text) type, using [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting):

```
var rawText = text => ({_rawType: true, toPostgres: () => text});
```

Create a generic default column, according to class [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html):

```
var defCol = name => ({name, def: rawText('DEFAULT')});
// which is the same as:
var defCol = name => new pgp.helpers.Column({name, def: rawText('DEFAULT')});
```

Generate the list of default-able columns:

```
var cols = Object.keys(inputObj).map(defCol);
```

Create a [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) with those columns:

```
var cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(cols, {table: 'my-table'});
```

When it is time to generate an insert query, you can do:

```
var insert = pgp.helpers.insert(inputObj, cs);
```

---

**Recommended Approach**

If you know the columns in advance, then you should just do the following:

```
var cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(
                    [defCol('column1'), defCol('column2'), defCol('column3')], 
                    {table: 'my-table'});
```

A static `cs` object will always provide a much better performance.

This approach is also safer, because you do not need to verify whether there is at least one property in the object, 'cos if there isn't, you'll get an error saying that it is impossible to generate an insert when there are no columns.

And this approach also works with multi-row inserts, which is very important. See also: [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).

Comment: Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'ColumnSet' of undefined.

Comment: My pgp is defined as var pgp = pgPromise('postgres://my-user@localhost/my-db');

Comment: Works! Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Syntax for Custom Type Formatting has been updated, as it changed in [v6.5.0](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.6.5.0).