# Using pgp.helpers.insert with RETURNING in statement

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I've got really good help with creating INSERT statements dynamically in a previous question: [NodeJS and pg-promise, insert dynamically from JSON-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225483/nodejs-and-pg-promise-insert-dynamically-from-json-object)

I've tried to look at the docs, and would like to include RETURNING in the INSERT statement, so I get the inserted record as output with pg-promise.

I'm using NodeJS with pg-promise.

Is it possible to return the inserted record with all columns?

Comment: See `Extras` section in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise

Comment: That was easy :) Thank you. Please make an answer, so I can credit you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do so simply by appending the `RETURNING` clause to your query, and then executing it with a method according to the expected result.

For a complete example see the **Extras** section in [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).