# pg-promise helpers : optionnal fields in insert and multiple-update

Tags: node.js, helper, pg-promise

pg-promise helpers : optionnal fields in insert and multiple-update

I have some question about non-required fields for insert and update statement

#### INSERT STATEMENT

With this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225483/nodejs-and-pg-promise-insert-dynamically-from-json-object) I defined a `ColumnSet` that contains optionals fields (`stype`, `sspeed`, `disup`). It works but I just want to know a little detail:
You can see that the `ColumnSet` define the value of `state` as "false" if the object don't have the property.
In the database the field "disup" is defined to "false" as default, so do I really need to define here the value as `false` or is there an other way to define optional columns ?
Imagine that I `ALTER TABLE` to change the default value to`TRUE` I will have to change the code.
[skip](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html#Column) parameter don't works with insert I don't understand how to use [partial](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/formatting.html#.format) (I think I can not use it here)

```js
cs.insert = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    /* hidden for brevity */
    { name: 'stype', prop: 'type', def:  { _rawType: true, toPostgres: () => null } },
    { name: 'sspeed', prop: 'speed', def:  { _rawType: true, toPostgres: () => null } },
    { name: 'disup', prop: 'state', def:  { _rawType: true, toPostgres: () => false } }
  ], {
    table: 'interfaces'
});

const objInsert = [
  { /* hidden for brevity */, state: false },
  { /* hidden for brevity */, speed: 2000, type: "Wired" }
];

pgp.helpers.insert(objInsert, cs.insert);
```

#### UPDATE STATEMENT

I need to define optional columns in an other `ColumnSet` but for UPDATE statement this time and I would like to use an array as input.
[skip](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html#Column) don't works with array, how to make "multiple update" query works with "optional" fields ? Is the answer "with a task or a batch" ? (I don't really understand what a batch does)
For example using

```js
cs.update = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    { name: 'interfaceid', prop: 'id', cnd: true },                          
    { name: 'updatedat', mod:'^', init: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)' },                     
    { name: 'siface', prop: 'iface', skip: col => !col.exists },
    { name: 'sipv4', prop: 'ipv4', cast: 'inet', skip: col => !col.exists },
    { name: 'sipv6', prop: 'ipv6', cast: 'inet', skip: col => !col.exists },
    { name: 'smac', prop: 'mac', cast: 'macaddr', skip: col => !col.exists },
    { name: 'stype', prop: 'type', skip: col => !col.exists },
    { name: 'sspeed', prop: 'speed', skip: col => !col.exists },
    { name: 'disup', prop: 'state', skip: col => !col.exists }
  ], {
    table: 'interfaces'
});

const objs =  [
    { id: 1, iface: "new value", state: false   },
    { id: 37, ipv4: "192.168.254.1" }
];

pgp.helpers.update(objs, cs.update); // throw "Property 'ipv4' doesn't exist." because objs is an array
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the database the field `disup` is defined to `false` as default, so do I really need to define here the value as `false` or is there an other way to define optional columns?

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. For example, if you want to use `false` when the property is missing, then instead of `skip: col => !col.exists`, you can use `def: false`.

> how to make "multiple update" query works with "optional" fields?

It is not possible. PostgreSQL syntax for multi-row updates doesn't allow such thing. It is [in documentation](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) - `skip` logic works only for single-row updates. And for multi-row updates you will have to provide default values there, as either `def` or `init`.

Also note that you are using a long-obsolete `_rawType` property for raw types. It was changed to `rawType` awhile ago. Or are you using an ancient version of the library? That wouldn't be good either, you should upgrade. And all online documentation refers to the latest release.

And the reason it works for you is because `def: { rawType: true, toPostgres: () => false }` can be reduced to just `def: false`. You do not need to use raw text, unless your function returns pre-formatted text.

**Extra**

If your [ColumnSet](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) objects for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are very similar, you can reduce the re-declaration, by using methods [extend](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html#extend) and [merge](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html#merge) ;)

Comment: I'm using pg-promise 8.7.2. I just didn't noticed that it is equivalent to `def: false`...
About the `skip`, the problem is that in the first part of my post I was talking about optional columns in 'INSERT' but I mis-explained a bit and after reflection I just can't because in the sql query all "VALUES" items must have the same format so all input object in the array must have the same properties, so pg-promise must add missing columns.
For your "extra" the problem is that 'INSERT' must use "deviceId" which is an FK while 'UPDATE' will never have to change this value