# Best Way To Save Data that keeps coming every 1 second to Postgres using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am building a project using node.js that is integrated with 4 other systems that keeps sending data from sensors every 1 second. I am trying to have like a timeline so I need to save that data, but I don't feel it's correct to hit a couple of insert statements every one second.

what is the best way to save data that is that redundant. I was thinking about having some log files and then insert data in bulk. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: You should look into mongo db or some similar nosql db to store data that frequently with relative ease

Comment: @gaganshera That is a stupid advise, considering PostgreSQL significantly outperforms those for multi-row insert operations, not to mention the data integrity that PostgreSQL brings with this by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would make it a premature optimization. I've bench-marked PostgreSQL under Node.js many times. And at any given moment inserting several records per second will take under 10ms, i.e. less than 1% of your app's load, if you do it every second.

The only worthwhile optimization you should do from start - use multi-row insert, even if you insert only 2 rows at a time. The reasons for this are as follows:

- Node.js IO is a valuable resource, so the fewer round trips you do the better
- Multi-row inserts are tremendously faster than separate insert queries
- Separate inserts typically require a transaction, and a single multi-row insert doesn't.

You can find a good example here: [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).

Comment: what about if the data are in different tables , i can still do multi-row insertion ?

Comment: @HasanAl-Natour each table would need its own insert query, obviously ;)

Comment: Am think of queuing insertions using RabbitmQ and let another instance of the application or a worker do the insert using a promise  , what do you think ?

Comment: @HasanAl-Natour The choice is all yours, and I already expressed in my answer what I think about all that. You are trying to solve a fictional problem.