# Array of Json into rows + postgresql + node.js

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql

Consider i have an array of json as follows

```
[
{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4} ,{"a":5,"b":6}
]
```

I have to insert this into postgtreSQL as follows:

```
in  out
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

I read about JSON datatypes in postgreSQL, but i couldn't figure out how to achieve this. please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wanted 'a', 'b' as column names?

Comment: you want to map 'in' with 'a' and 'out' with 'b'?

Comment: Can you please tell, from where the JSON data is coming? or its always 'a' and 'b' as key?

Comment: Have you tried using JSON parser?

Comment: @sForSujit JSON parser is for parsing the JSON , but my question is how can i convert this array of JSON into rows in postgresql.

Comment: @Subburaj you can use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into my_table (in, out)
select a, b
from jsonb_to_recordset(
    '[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4} ,{"a":5,"b":6}]'
) r (a int, b int)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE

In Javascript escape the single quotes:

```
var query = 'insert into table (enroll_id, time) select enroll_id, time from jsonb_to_recordset(\'' + data + '\') r (enroll_id bigserial, time timestamp)';
```

Comment: Thanks.. but if i construct a query like `var query = 'insert into table (enroll_id, time) select EnrollNumber, time from jsonb_to_recordset( '+data+') r (enroll_id bigserial, time timestamp)';` Here data is the json Array but its not  a valid query. how can i rectify this??

Comment: @Subburaj Escape the single quotes.

Comment: `{ error: column "enrollnumber" does not exist` throwing error

Comment: @Subburaj `select enroll_id`

Comment: according to  ur query `select enroll_id, time from jsonb_to_recordset` but in the JSON the key what we have is `EnrollNumber` then how it will select enroll_id from JSON set..

Comment: enroll_id is not selected its empty in table, i think we have to change enroll_id to 'EnrollNumber' at the last part