# How to insert array of values in postgresql using nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, postgresql, postman

```js
for(i in req.body.category_id){
db.query('INSERT INTO guide_categories(category_id) values($1)', [req.body.category_id[i]],function(err,category) {
  if(err) return next(err);                         
  return console.log("success");           
  });                             
}
```

Here I am passing the array of values from postman as `category_id:["3","1"]`, and only the last value of the array is being inserted and the rest are not. How do I solve this?

Comment: how do you know its not inserted?.. `db.query` is async?..

Comment: I am checking database every time.

Comment: Multiple inserts should be done via a single, multi-insert query. Example: [Multi-row insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
for(i in req.body.category_id){
db.query('INSERT INTO guide_categories(category_id) values($1) returning *', [req.body.category_id[i]], (err,category) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);     
    } else {                    
    console.log(category);   
  }        
  };                             
}
```

and populate the output of `console.log`

Comment: I assume you return after first iteration?.. not going for next results