# Bulk INSERT for records that don't exist, returning ID

Tags: pg-promise

I'm using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/) to process an array of data that I want to insert in table A. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to dynamically create this query that should only INSERT those values not already present in the table, while returning the ID of all those who are already present or were newly created.

I'm doing the following to do the above, but for a single element:

```
WITH s as
  ( SELECT *
   FROM fruits
   WHERE fruit_name = 'Apple' ),
       i AS
  ( INSERT INTO fruits(fruit_name) SELECT 'Apple'
   WHERE NOT exists
       (SELECT 1
        FROM s) RETURNING fruit_id)
```

But say that I have an Array of fruits = `['Banana', 'Apple']`. How would I use the helpers to generate a query that would return the existing ID for apple, and the one for Banana?

Comment: Please share any code that you have tried so far and any error messages.

Comment: @RyanNerd I've updated my answer. I haven't written anything meaningful since I've got no idea on where to start :/

Comment: Check out [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise). Maybe you can use that with an upsert logic.

Comment: @vitaly-t Done! I used that [with this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057586/bulk-insert-for-records-that-dont-exist-returning-id?noredirect=1#comment89117067_51057586) to create the query. Thanks!