# Is it possible to get `INSERT oid count` data after INSERT command with pg-promise?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

When I use psql, there is confirmation after INSERT command.
For example:

```
t34=# INSERT INTO t VALUES ('test');
INSERT 0 1
```

Is it possible to get this data (0, 1) with pg-promise package?

P.S. I speak about output `INSERT oid count`

Comment: `pg-promise` gives you a promise. When the promise resolves - that's your confirmation.

Comment: Yeah exactly, the 'then' functions execution tells you that the insertion is made successfully

Comment: @vitaly-t Sorry, I think my original question was not clear. Is it possible to get INSERT oid count data? As I understand, db.none() returns Promise<null>
I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.one('INSERT INTO t VALUES($1) RETURNING *', 'test')
    .then(data => {
        /* data = the inserted row object */
    })
    .catch(error => {
        /* failed */
    });
```

See method [one](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#one).

Relevant reads: [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).