# Relation not found error in multi-row insert with postgresql and pg-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm developing a **nodejs** project with a **postgresql-db**. 
I've created a **schema** for the db with some tables and now I've created a file with some prepared data (multilple rows) to insert. For that I followed the instructions of this entry: [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).

The problem is, that I get following error: **{ error: relation "tenantx.ObjectGroup" does not exist** ... but it does. I can also see that from my api, when I want to read the table content, it returns an empty object.
Can the "schema.table"-declaration be the reason?

The code for the prepared data looks like this:

```
    'use strict';
     const pgp = require('pg-promise')({
                // Initialization Options
            });

        const csObjectGroup = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['objectgroup', 'description'], {
                    table: 'tenantx.ObjectGroup'
                });
                // data input values:
                const valuesObjectGroup = [{
                    objectgroup: 'bla',
                    description: 'bla'
                }, {
                    objectgroup: 'blu',
                    description: 'blu'
                }, {
                    objectgroup: 'bla',
                    description: 'bla'
                }];
module.exports = {
    csObjectGroup: csObjectGroup,
    valuesObjectGroup: valuesObjectGroup
}
```

And the code which is called from api to setup content:
// insert prepared data into tables

```
function initializeData(pTenantId, dbUri) {
    var dbPostgres = dbUri;
    const datafile = require("./../Data/data_" + pTenantId);

    var statements = [];

    var valuesObjectGroup = datafile.valuesObjectGroup;
    var csObjectGroup = datafile.csObjectGroup;

    statements.push(valuesObjectGroup, csObjectGroup);

    var i, query;
    for (i = 0; i < statements.length - 1; i += 2) {
        query = pgp.helpers.insert(statements[i], statements[i + 1]);
        dbPostgres.none(query)
            .then(data => {
                console.log("+++++ Data successfully initialized.");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("----- Data could not be initialized.");
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've created the table from this:

```
const createObjectGroupTable =
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tenantx.ObjectGroup \
            ( \
                id serial, \
                objectgroup varchar(50), \
                description varchar(100), \
                PRIMARY KEY (id) \
            )';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the reported error with more attention:

> { error: relation "tenantx.ObjectGroup" does not exist ...

That's not `"tenantx"."ObjectGroup"`, that's just one table name `"tenantx.ObjectGroup"`.

And the problem originates from the way you declare the table:

```
const csObjectGroup = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['objectgroup', 'description'], {
                    table: 'tenantx.ObjectGroup'
                });
```

instead of providing schema + table names, you specify it all as a table name, and so it is escaped accordingly.

The correct way to specify schema + table can be done in one of the following ways:

```
table: {schema: 'tenantx', table: 'ObjectGroup'}
```

or:

```
table: new pgp.helpers.TableName('ObjectGroup', 'tenantx')
```

or:

```
table: new pgp.helpers.TableName({table: 'ObjectGroup', schema: 'tenantx'})
```

See API: [TableName](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.TableName.html).

Comment: I've tried now all three possibilities, but I get always the same error. I also logged the tablename and it seems to be right concanated: "tenantx"."ObjectGroup". Can there be another reason? The log says: `***** "tenantx"."ObjectGroup"
----- Data could not be initialized.
{ error: relation "tenantx.ObjectGroup" does not exist [...]`

Comment: Logs with logged columnset say: `***** ColumnSet {
table: "tenantx"."ObjectGroup"
columns: [
Column {
name: "objectgroup"
}
Column {
name: "description"
}
]
}
----- Data could not be initialized.
{ error: relation "tenantx.Object" does not exist`

Comment: One difference is, that my pgp.helpers.insert(...) is a var and no const because of the for loop. Can it be a reason?

Comment: First, it was `tenantx.ObjectGroup`, now it is `tenantx.Object`. I don't know what you really did there, I cannot see the code, but something isn't right on your side. The solution I gave you must fix exactly the error you showed.

Comment: Those are both tables as I have more than only one. Probably I have copied the log not in the right order, I'm sorry.  Well, this is weird..