# How to fix function with postgres query to prevent SQL injection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sql-injection, pg-promise

I need help fixing a function I've written (in a node.js serverless microservice) to prevent sql injection. I'm new to security topics so any ideas or points in the right direction would be awesome, thanks!

Here's the function from **RecipientAlerts.js:**

```
  updateRecipient(email, body, callback) {
    helper.removeRecipient(this.db, email) // clears old data
      .then(() => {
        const values = Object.keys(body).map(industry => 
          body[industry].map(company => 
            `('${company}', '${industry}', '${email}')`).join(', ')).join(', ');
        const insert =`INSERT INTO recipient_list(company, industry, email_address) VALUES `;
        this.db.queries.none(insert + values)             
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error, 'error on insert query', callback);
          });
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('successfully updated', null, callback);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error, 'failed to update recipient', callback);
      });
  }
```

Here's the **recipient.json**:

```
{ 
    "pathParameters": {
        "email": "john@gmail.com"
    },
    "body": {
        "tech": ["Apple"],
        "hospitality": ["McDonalds", "Subway"],
        "banking": ["Citi", "HSBC"]
    }
}
```

The expected result (which I'm currently getting and want to stay the same) is:
**recipient_list** table:

```
company       |  industry   | email_address
______________|_____________|________________
Apple         | tech        | john@gmail.com
--------------|-------------|---------------
McDonalds     | hospitality | john@gmail.com
--------------|-------------|---------------
Subway        | hospitality | john@gmail.com
--------------|-------------|---------------
Citi          | banking     | john@gmail.com
--------------|-------------|---------------
HSBC          | banking     | john@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [Multi-Row Inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise) examples with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), declare a [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) object once:

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    'company',
    'industry',
    {name: 'email_address', prop: 'email'}
], {table: 'recipient_list'});
```

Then you can change your code to this:

```
updateRecipient(email, body, callback)
{
    helper.removeRecipient(this.db, email) // clears old data
        .then(() => {
            const insert = pgp.helpers.insert(body, cs); // generating the INSERT query
            this.db.queries.none(insert) // executing the INSERT query
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error, 'error on insert query', callback);
                });
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('successfully updated', null, callback);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error, 'failed to update recipient', callback);
        });
}
```

The SQL will be generated safely this way, and immune to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use sequelize , it will handle it automatically

[Here is the doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-usage.html)