# how do I insert many, if it already exists, dont do anything with PG-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

The error: `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"`

I am using Node and PG-Promise

I am bulk inserting a bunk of data into my database. Sometimes, the data already exists so I need to either overwrite it or just ignore that row.

I saw that I can do this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do that with PG-Promise when I am bulk inserting.

```
let users = [...]
const query = pgp.helpers.insert(users, userTable)
```

What would the syntax look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76774547/5079799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/542,

> simply append the `ON CONFLICT` part to your query, and that's it.

So in your case

```js
const users = […];
const query = pgp.helpers.insert(users, cs) + ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE';
```

Where `cs` is your [ColumnSet](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) object. You also will typically use [assignColumns](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html#assignColumns) method, as you can see from the same link.

Notice that the [proper Postgres `INSERT` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) uses `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE …`.

Comment: Yep, just about, but perhaps he will need to use `ON CONFLICT(col1, col2) DO UPDATE SET` syntax instead. I also added the [assignColumns](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html#assignColumns) reference.