# Using Promise.all inside a transaction / task vs using t.batch in pg-promise

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pg-promise

The documentation [here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Common-Mistakes#tasks-versus-rootdirect-queries) clearly outlines that it is a bad practice to write

```
Promise.all(data.map(d => db.none('insert into...', d)))
```

which is querying against root database protocol. Hence it is better to write

```
db.task(t => t.batch(data.map(d => t.none('insert into...', d))));
```

However, is it wrong to write this if I do not intend to use `BatchError` or query `duration`  ([ref](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch))?

```
db.task(async t => {
  await Promise.all(data.map(d => t.none('insert into...', d)));
});
```

By the looks of it, it still uses shared connection protocol instead of root connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coming of ES7 with `async/await` to the scene, dissipated the need for putting queries in a batch.

You can simply do this instead:

```js
await db.task(async t => {
    await forEachAsync(data, d => t.none('insert into...', d));
});
```

or just return the result:

```js
await db.task(t => forEachAsync(data, d => t.none('insert into...', d)));
```

That would need async for-each function like this:

```js
async function forEachAsync(data, cb) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        await cb(data[i], i, data);
    }
}
```

But normally, you do not need any of these when executing an array of inserts, because for that you should be using [multi-row inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise) instead.