# PG Promise too many client on high concurrent request

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

im trying to inserting hundred / thousand data based on selected data from others table, but i found an error "too many clients", here is the error [image: too many client]

Im using pgp (pg promise) lib, here is my snippet

```
function call(){
   for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
        getPendingData().then((result) => {
            db.tx((t) => {
                let counter = 0;
                const queries = result.map((data) => {
                    counter++;
                    return db.none(`insert into test_data (id, isdeleted, parentid) values ('${uuidv1()}', 0, '${uuidv1()}x-${uuidv1()}' ) `);
                });
                return t.batch(queries);
            });
        });
   }
}


let  getPendingData = async () => {
     return db.task('getPendingData', async (t) => {
         return await t.any('select * from other_table');
     });
}


(call())
```

im setup max pg conn is 100,
any clue how to solved this without add max conn?

Comment: Install [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html), then run a single `insert into test_data (id, isdeleted, parentid) select uuid_generate_v1()::text, 0, uuid_generate_v1()::text || 'x-' uuid_generate_v1()::text from other_table;` query.

Comment: @Bergi i think issue not comming from uuid, its comming from client conn

Comment: No, the issue is coming from your approach. Don't make hundredths or thousands of queries to the database (even in a transaction), if the database can do all the work in a simple single query.

Comment: but i need to insert a lot data bases on selected queries, and the queries return a thousand of rows

Comment: Just split queries into chunks and run only chunk queries in parallel and process all chunks sequentially. For instance, you can split an array of queries using `lodash` `chunk` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are too many problems in your code, unfortunately...

It is incorrect both in how you use promises, and in how you use `pg-promise`.

The issue with the promises is that you're supposed to chain them, that means using the result from `db.tx` (`return db.tx(...)`), which you're not doing, creating a loose promise, and as a result, a loose connection associated with the transaction. Also, `return await` is an anti-pattern.

The issue with `pg-promise` usage is that you're supposed to execute queries against the transaction/task context `t` that you are creating ([as shown here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Chaining-Queries)). But you're executing each query against `db` - root connection instead, which spawns countless connection requests.

Also, creating a task to execute just one query doesn't make any sense.

If that's not bad enough, you're doing string concatenation for values, which is a strict no-no in query formatting.

And the last, multiple inserts should be executed as multi-row queries, not as separate queries, which is a waste of performance - see [multi-row inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).

Comment: Thank you for `pg-promise` :)