# How to bulk Insert in POSTGRES using Express API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, api, express

My web application sends data in below format

```
data = {User: [{id:"1",name:"Smith",email:"simth@test.com"},{id:"2",name:"Roy",email:"roy@test.com"}], Color: "Orange", Shape: "Triangle"}
```

We need to create an API to insert the above data received into our POSTGRES database table. The table has columns Email, Color and Shape. So based on the sample data above there will be two inserts that will happen

```
1. Email:simth@test.com, Color: Orange, Shape: Triangle
2. Email: roy@test.com, Color: Orange, Shape: Triangle
```

Please note the data received cannot be modified now. How do we handle this in Express or Postgres and do bulk insert of the records.

Comment: Please check, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise.

Comment: I assume that even if you cannot modifiy the way data received, you should be able to parse data after receive it.