# Laravel Increment by Multiplying Two Columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent, increment

Trying to do something like:

```
$variance = mt_rand (2, 12) / 10;
DB::table('resources')->increment('grainQuant', 'grainLQ' * 'grainPM' * $variance));
```

All three values are on the same row, and I want to iterate through every row. The below works fine, but I can't figure out how to multiply in the other column values (and update every single row).

```
$variance = mt_rand (2, 12) / 10;
DB::table('resources')->increment('grainQuant', $variance));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use raw sql  :

```
DB::update('UPDATE "resources" SET "grainQuant" = "grainLQ" * "grainPM" * ?', [$variance]);
```

Or even

```
DB::update("UPDATE \"resources\" SET \"grainQuant\" = \"grainLQ\" * \"grainPM\" * $variance");
```

Comment: Can't get either of those to work, or even using `DB::update('update resources set landQuant = 1 where id = 1');`

Comment: What's the error ? Does `DB::select('SELECT * FROM resources');` give you all the results ?

Comment: That's weird it's saying `SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "landquant" of relation "resources" does not exist`  but it does exist...

Comment: Just looked up and according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189254/pgerror-error-column-of-relation-does-not-exist-rails-heroku postgresql lowercases non quoted strings, I've updated my answer. However, if it still does not work, this is more of a postgresql question, unless someone knows a way to do it in laravel

Comment: Why are you using double quotes and not backticks?

Comment: @fubar I haven't ever used postgresql and it is what they use in the link above. Feel free to edit my answer if you feel that they are more appropriate

Comment: Me neither. Apparently backticks are a MySQL thing. Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code

```
$variance = mt_rand (2, 12) / 10;
DB::table('resources')->increment('grainQuant', DB::raw("grainLQ * grainPM * ".$variance));
```

This will only work if 'grainLQ' and 'grainPM' is a column in resources table